# Adding "alt" content to canvas

Tags: html, canvas, selection, copy-paste

I am writing a program that embeds text in canvases, each canvas contains one character (Kanji) that will be animated, drawn one stroke at a time.

I have encountered a few problems so far:

1. The user cannot select the canvases.
2. The use cannot copy the text, as there is no text, but just images.

I might have overcome the second issue by inserting the text inside the `<canvas>` tag (though I have no way to check if it works, as I can't select the canvases to copy the content); but I have no idea on how to solve the first issue.

So the question is: how can I make my canvases behave as images with `alt` attributes, so that users can copy them as if they were normal characters?

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mg6c9qe8/) with `<img alt="...">`

Thanks!

#### UPDATE

I have written a few more tests:

- [`div` with `canvas` + absolutely positioned `img`](http://jsfiddle.net/mg6c9qe8/6/)

  **Issues:** adds spaces between `div` elements (tested on Firefox), selection sometimes flickers.
- [`canvas` + partially hidden `span`](http://jsfiddle.net/mg6c9qe8/7/)

  **Issues:** selection completely hides the canvas.

I've also tried with labels, but there were even more issues and no noticeable advantage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such `alt` attribute to canvas element.

From "[MDN - Basic Usage of canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage)":

> At first sight a `<canvas>` looks like the `<img>` element, with the only clear difference being that it doesn't have the src and alt attributes.

Also, the innerHTML of the canvas will only be accessible to browsers which don't support `<canvas>` element.

What you could do however, *if you only draw once on the canvas and if there is no Cross-Origin involved in those drawings (i.e external images)*, is to create new `<img>` tags with their `src` set to the `canvas.toDataURL()`, and assign those an alt attribute.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
  canvas.parentNode.replaceChild(this, canvas);
  this.alt = 'your alt content';
  }
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Or alternatively, for your particular case, you could also append a `<span>`element with its opacity set to 0 , its height/width to 1px and positionning it absolutely.

It should not be visible, but you would be able to copy paste its content.

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  cursor: text;
  height: 1em;
}
.canvas_alt {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 1px;
  max-width: 1px;
  opacity: 0
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
Copy the images as if text:
<br />
<br />X<canvas height="50" width="50"></canvas><span class="canvas_alt">alt text</span>Y
<br />
<br />Try pasting it here, is should be 'XiiY':
<br />
<input />
```

Comment: Your second proposal is very similar to my latest attempt, I guess this is about the best that can be done, I also thought about replacing the canvas with an image after the animation is completed, that would unfortunately prevent selection while animation is running and I couldn't repeat the animation later.

The problems with the second approach are that the selection would be invisible, and a SHIFT + ARROW selection would require some presses to go through the hidden elements, with no feedback at all.

I'm probably going to accept your answer, thanks for sharing your time and expertise.

Comment: @bruce965 you could also try [to change the img src on every frame](http://jsfiddle.net/mg6c9qe8/8/), if canvases are small, I hope that performances won't suffer too much, or you could try to [override the copied data](http://jsfiddle.net/mg6c9qe8/9/)

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to "hack" it by putting an image with opacity 0 on top of the canvas element, with the same height and width, both positioned absolute.

```css
.myParentElem{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.myCanvas{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.myImg{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="myParentElem>
  <canvas class="myCanvas">
  <img class="myImg" alt="my alt text">
</div>
```